# Blank screen on Facebook login on Edge browser

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, microsoft-edge

tl;dr: I get a blank popup screen after logging in to Facebook on Edge and it doesn't return to my site.

Hello. I have a working Facebook login flow under Chrome and Firefox and Internet Explorer 11, yet when I try the same flow with Edge browser on Windows 10 it fails miserably. I'm using JavaScript. I tried to search for answers but did not find something relevant.

### What happens

On Edge, I click my login button, the popup appears and I enter my credentials. After hitting 'login' on the Facebook popup, it redirects to a blank page. The URL of that blank popup page has many query parameters and one of them is the redirect address to my site that I provided, yet the popup stays blank and I face the dreaded White Screen Of Death. If I go to facebook.com I can see that I am logged in, so the login did work behind the scenes.

I went futher and tried the **official Facebook JS example** taken from their development site. That **didn't work** as well!

I have checked a few other Facebook logins on other sites and their flow works. Something very strange is going on and I kind of ran out of ideas how to debug this.

Here are some query parameters (converted to JSON for brevity) with all what seemed to be private hidden:

*The URL of the popup when I am the login page. There are scary errors but I think they are related only to when the login fails.*

```
{
  "version": "42#cb",
  "domain": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "origin": "http%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "relation": "opener",
  "frame": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "error": "access_denied",
  "error_code": "200",
  "error_description": "Permissions+error",
  "error_reason": "user_denied",
  "e2e": "%7B%7D",
  "display": "popup"
}
```

*This is the URL when I get the blank page. Again, all this flow works on Chrome and IE 11 on Windows 10 but not on Edge (didn't test Firefox there yet).*

```
{
  "version": "42#cb",
  "domain": [
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  ],
  "origin": [
    "http%3A%2F%2FXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX%2Ff3ab15014b2d67e",
    "1"
  ],
  "relation": "opener",
  "frame": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "display": "popup",
  "scope": "email,public_profile,user_friends,user_events,user_location,rsvp_event",
  "response_type": "token,signed_request",
  "client_id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "ret": "login",
  "sdk": "joey",
  "ext": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "hash": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

What am I missing? Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Having the same issue here, investing whether or not its another social plugin causing the issue, since earlier this morning before i added "like, follow buttons" the login was working fine.

Answer (score 3):

**Internet Options Trusted Sites.**  I was able to fix this random issue by adding my site and facebook wildcard entries to my Trusted Sites.

Access by going to:

1. Control Panel
2. Internet Options
3. Click Security Tab
4. Click Trusted Sites Tab
5. Click Sites Button & add sites in format *as seen in image below*.

[image: JSSKD v2.5 Login Button and Window]

[image: Windows 10 Internet Options & Trusted Sites]

Comment: That's interesting. I will try that to see if it helps, but it wouldn't be a good fix beause you can't count on your users to customize their browser just to visit and use your website.

Comment: I totally understand, and i have been searching far and wide for a cause to this.  My only guess is that security such as avast has modified settings recently in an update.  Since everything worked fine about a week ago in edge.

Comment: That is indeed the problem. Also for IE11. Any idea which setting in the trusted zone actually makes the difference and if there is a workaround for this situation?

Comment: Not yet @Karens currently i am unable to reproduce this error.  Have reinstalled IE and EDGE from dev version available at time of Q and on.  I believe this to be bad coding in security software, possibly using activex permissions.